# $B>A>C$ here ? where $A,B,$ are average of some numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: I want to find a relations between $A,B,C$]

I see, $B=2A-100^{12}\Rightarrow B>A$ and $C+1/50=A/2\Rightarrow C<A$ am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $B<C$. For compare the first terms $1^{13}$ and $2^{13}$; the second terms $3^{13}$ and $4^{13}$; the third terms $5^{13}$ and $6^{13}$; and so on. In each case the term in $C$ is bigger than the corresponding term of $B$.

Now we leave placing $A$ to you. Show that $A$ is the average of $B$ and $C$.